# How to include static html pages into my NodeJS project

Tags: node.js, html, pug

I have a NodeJS project setup. I want to integrate my static html pages into it. Where can I do it ?

Thank you  !

Comment: Are you using some kind of library such as Express for rendering? I see you've tagged Jade, I figured it was a useful question; the approach and possible solutions will differ based on what you're working with.

Comment: Yes I'm using Express. Sorry to have not mentioned it earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expose static html, create a directory named "public" that lives next to your primary application file (app.js).

Assuming you are using the express framework, you can expose this directory by using the following code:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

where

```
var app = express();
```

Subsequently, any request to "/{something}" will attempt to resolve a route to a static file in your public directory, so if you had a file named {something} in that directory it would get served right up.